# KNN with bagging in R

Tags: r, k-nearest-neighbour, bagging

How to implement bagging with KNN using R in order to reduce the variability?

This is the R code that I use for KNN

```
knn.pred <- knn(training, testing, target_variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that this is what you are asking for but the package [FNN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/FNN.pdf) implements the bagged nn in its `ownn` function.